# Replacing linked objects with instanced collections

Tags: modeling, linked-data, instances

I know how to replace Objects (Mesh data) (ctrl+L > Mesh data), but how do I replace a series of linked objects with an instanced collection?

My example: [image]

I want to replace the stair steps with the more detailed liked collection. The steps are one object each, linked to each other.

Best regards,
Chris